# ASP.NET MVC (4) - Prevent calling IValidatableObject.Validate for properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I prevent calling `IValidatableObject.Validate` for properties and call it for the top level model only?

```
public abstract class Foo, IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual Foo Related { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // This is first called for the 'Related' property 
        // and then for the model itself
        // I want this to be called for the top level model only
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a more elegant way, but what about creating a new class overriding the Validate method of Foo?

Something like:

```
public class FooNoValidation : Foo
{
    public override IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Of course this would require the Validate method on Foo to be virtual and you to refer to FooNoValidation on the Foo parent class, but might work.

I know its a bit of a hack, but if you just need to get this to work this should make that happen.